# Why Am I getting "missing 1 positional argument" error for this class?

Tags: python, class, properties

I have a simple class. I want to set the `periodicity` property using a private attribute which is tested before being used to set the public attribute. I am passing self around the class module, when I run the test code the function seems to expect 2 arguments. I thought it should ignore `self` and ask for the one `freq` parameter. I am trying to be "pythonic" and use `@property` with `.setter`. Do I need to change the property call? If I remove `self` from `set_periodicity` it says it does not recognize `self`.

```
class ModelSetUp:

    def __init__(self):
        self.periodicity= None

    @property
    def set_periodicity(self,freq):
        self.periodicity = self._periodicity

    @set_periodicity.setter
    def set_periodicity(self,freq):
        if freq in ("Q","S","A"):
            self._periodicity = freq
        else:
            raise ValueError("Frequency Must Be Q, S or A")

if __name__=="__main__":
    mod = ModelSetUp()
    mod.set_periodicity("Q")
```

Comment: That implementation doesn't make any sense. Why do you have a property named `set_...` that you're then using like a regular setter method anyway? Why is the getter implementation setting an attribute value (from the value of another attribute that may not even exist yet)?

Comment: Because setter is used when you assign a new value with `=`. So `mod.set_periodicity = "Q"`. And just a suggestion: rename `set_periodicity` to `periodicity` because it acts like `property` not a method. Also, `@property` should not take any arguments (except `self`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties don't take any arguments, nor are they callable. Try this:

```py
class ModelSetUp:

    def __init__(self):
        self._periodicity = None

    @property
    def periodicity(self):
        return self._periodicity

    @periodicity.setter
    def periodicity(self, freq):
        if freq in ("Q","S","A"):
            self._periodicity = freq
        else:
            raise ValueError("Frequency Must Be Q, S or A")

if __name__=="__main__":
    mod = ModelSetUp()
    mod.periodicity = "Q"
```

Comment: It would probably be less confusing if the property itself was named `periodicity` instead of `set_periodicity`